# Entry point of a program

Tags: disassembly, assembly, ollydbg

im new to assembly and reverse engineering, i have a question regarding to how the address work.
I examined the entry point of a program using varies PE tools, the result is **0x00043b33**, but when i loaded the same program into ollydbg, the starting address is at **0x770B0D54**. Another thing is i executed the program line by line, it somehow jump back to the entry point at **0x00043b33** and then go back to the address **0x770B0D54** later again. Can someone guide me on this？

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter where you want to break. The address `0x770B0D54` is in kernel code and it's probably before kernel starts executing user code. Useful if there's some magic happening before `main` is executed and you want to step through that.

On the other hand `0x00043b33` is int user code and it's probably the address of the `main` function so that is the real code of the application.

In OllyDbg you can control the initial breakpoint in Options->Debugging, Startup and exit
[image]